# How to filter one dataframe on the basis of other

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandasql

I have one dataframe, I need to filter the dates on the basis of start and end date of the other dataframe.

df1 should have all_dates that is in the range of start_date and end_date of df2

example set is given below. What is the best way in pandas to achieve that?

Considering sample dataframes as below, I have included the expected result set

```
df1 

ID all_date   clicks
1  2019-08-21   5
1  2019-08-22   4
1  2019-08-25   2
1  2019-08-27   2
2  2019-07-18   5
2  2019-07-21   5
2  2019-07-23   6
2  2019-07-25   6
2  2019-07-27   6

df2

ID start_date  end_date
1  2019-08-21 2019-08-23
2  2019-07-18 2019-07-24
```

```
expected output:

df1

ID all_date   clicks
1  2019-08-21   5
1  2019-08-22   4
2  2019-07-18   5
2  2019-07-21   5
2  2019-07-23   6
```

Output should contain range of date i.e start_date and end_date of df2

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) first and filter by [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) with `loc` for filter by columns names and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1['all_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['all_date'])
df2['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['start_date'])
df2['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['end_date'])

df = df1.merge(df2, on='ID')
df = df.loc[df['all_date'].between(df['start_date'], df['end_date']), df1.columns]
print (df)
   ID   all_date  clicks
0   1 2019-08-21       5
1   1 2019-08-22       4
4   2 2019-07-18       5
5   2 2019-07-21       5
6   2 2019-07-23       6
```